# Need to identify Java version usage on an IBM i partition

Tags: java, jvm, ibm-midrange

In order to scope remediation and testing activities for a potential IBM i upgrade, I would like to run some sort of monitor or collection service that can tell me which of the various installed IBM i Java versions are actually being used in practice, and which jobs are invoking them.

I'm not looking for a 3rd party tool, just advice on how IBM i built in tools might be leveraged to achieve this, since the web seems silent on this point.

I wouldn’t need the classpaths, Java stats, etc. – just which Java version. (Even knowing simply that a Java activity had been kicked off by a particular job at a particular time would be beneficial.)

WRKJVMJOB is fine for a snapshot, but that's not really what I want.

There appears to be something called 'Java Collection' in QMGTOOLS, but I can find no documentation online, and I suspect this is a red herring given the specific purpose of QMGTOOLS.

Currently on V7R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object audit (including read) on the QJVM* library objects does the job.